# How to downgrade ZFS On Linux on CentOS

Tags: centos, package-management, zfs

I need to do some testing of ZFS on CentOS 7.3 using the 0.6.5 branch, not the 0.7x branch.  When I install using the ZoL site instructions for "zfs-release" package I only see listings for the 0.7x versions. I prefer to use the kmod install too, just fyi, but I figure once I solve the versioning I'll be ok on that.

We are having issues with some software being very very slow on that version of ZFS and the older versions on other systems are fast so I thought we would just downgrade to test, but I can't simply run a "yum list all |grep zfs" to get the 0.6.5x series rpms.

I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It just wasn't clear because unless I had already installed zfs-release (even if its newer than I want), I could not see any packages.  However, once that was installed for EL7_3, I could run this:

```
yum search zfs* --show-duplicates
```

Which then shows all the packages, so I ran this:

```
yum install zfs-0.6.5.11-1.el7.centos spl-0.6.5.11-1.el7.centos
```

This installed normal from this point.